# Grails 3.0 encoding não funciona fora do index.gsp

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação, grails

Estou criando um projeto Grails com a versão 3.0.4 e algo estranho ocorre:

Duas GSPs com o mesmo conteúdo:

views > index.gsp: 
views > domain > show.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
çççççççç óóóó úúúúúú ááá´´aááááá´´a´´´ççççç
    </body>
</html>
```

Resultado **views > index.gsp:**
çççççççç óóóó úúúúúú ááá´´aááááá´´a´´´ççççç

Resultado **views > domain > show.gsp:**
�������� ���� ������ ��ᴴa����ᴴa��������

Alguém entende o motivo?

Answer (score 0):

Foi um problema simples na verdade. Basta configurar o encoding do arquivo gsp.

Como o Grails criou automáticamente para mim o index.gsp ele já configurou o arquivo como UTF-8. E os que eu criei foram automaticamente para outro encoding.

No meu caso é o IntelliJ que estou me acostumando ainda. Para alterar, só botão direito no arquivo e "file encoding", mas recomendo utilizar o mesmo encoding para todo o projeto: File > Setings > Editor > File Encodings